Book recommendations on curves.
I've recently become fascinated by the geometry of curves, especially topics that involve rolling curves, trajectories, and dynamics within these structures. My interest started with some YouTube videos that delve into subjects like firing a laser within an ellipse and observing its path, as well as exploring various types of curves like cycloid, nephroid etc. My background in calculus (particularly from studying Calculus II) has made me curious about the mathematical principles behind these phenomena.
Is there a specific branch of mathematics that focuses on the study of such topics, like rolling curves or trajectories within curves? If so, what is it called, and what are the prerequisites for studying it? Additionally, could anyone recommend some comprehensive books or resources that cover this area in depth?
As a self-learner without access to formal classes, I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to approach studying this field independently. Thank you in advance!

See the references (excluding Ruth Eversole's thesis) in my answer to Which book has functions and their respective graphs? and the references in my answer to how do you graph a function?

There's alot of different definitions of a curve.  I think Felix Klein remarked on this.  You, also,  may wish to check out some low dimensional differential geometry texts.
